# Regex Matching: Surrounded by space or start of line, but not matched

Tags: javascript, regex

This is what I have so far: `/(^|[\s])#\d+/g`

My test string is: `"#123 it should match this: #1234, but not this: http://example.org/derp#6326 . How about on a new line?\n\n#1284"`

When I attempt to match, I get the following matches:

- `"#123"`
- `" #1234"`
- `"\n#1284"` (pretend that's an actual line break in there)

I attempted to change the regular expression by adding `?:` to the grouping, and surrounding what I wanted with parenthesis: `/(?:^|[\s])(#\d+)/g`, however, this did not work, and provided the same matches

How can I match just the `#` + numbers, without anything before it?

Comment: Since you can't use look-behind in JavaScript you need to use memory captures instead.

Comment: Yeah, look-behind was one of the first thing I tried, but of course, not available in js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A memory capture will do the trick:

```
var re = /(?:^|[\s])(#\d+)/g;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/suqusofo/1/)

Comment: @JulianH.Lam It works okay in the demo; did you check it out?

Comment: Thanks @Jack -- I ran it incorrectly in the Chrome Inspector. Seems I need to read up on memory captures :), works great!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you did capture what you wanted, you just need to look at what's inside the capturing group and not at the whole match...

Try

```
var myString = "#123 it should match this: #1234, but not this: http://example.org/derp#6326 . How about on a new line?\n\n#1284";
var myRegex = /(?:^|\s)(#\d+)/g;
var allMatches = [];
while((result = myRegex.exec(myString)) != null) {
    var match = result[1]; // get the first capturing group of the current match
    allMatches.push(match);
}
```

You can see what the regex captures clearly [here](http://regex101.com/r/yV9gF6)

Answer (score 0):

```
subject= "#1234, but not this: http://example.org/derp#6326";
match = subject.match(/^\s*?#(\d+)/m);
if (match != null) {
    var result =  match[1]
}

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “#” literally «#»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\d+)»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```